# Strange ode question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve

$$x^2(x+y)(dx + dy) = y(xdy - ydx)$$

> It is not exact, is it homogenous?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably want to make use of the facts that $$d(xy)=ydx+xdy$$ $$d(y/x)=\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}$$

Comment: Maybe they meant to write $xdy-ydx$ on the RHS

Comment: correct. typo fixed.

Comment: Any idea? to see the explicit Matthew?  i got what you wrote?

Comment: $$\left(x^3+x^2 y+y^2\right)dx+\left(x^3+x^2 y-x y\right)dy=0$$

Comment: @raffaele it does not work. it is not exact.

Comment: It's: $y'(x)=-\frac{x^2 y+x^3+y^2}{x \left(x^2+x y-y\right)}$ and Maple says: $-{\it \_C1}+{\frac {1}{x} \left( \ln  \left( -9\,{\frac {x}{{x}^{2}-y
 \left( x \right) +y \left( x \right) x}} \right) x-\ln  \left( {
\frac {9\,{x}^{2}+9\,y \left( x \right) x-9\,x-9\,y \left( x \right) 
}{2\,{x}^{2}-2\,y \left( x \right) +2\,y \left( x \right) x}} \right) 
x-{x}^{2}-y \left( x \right) x+y \left( x \right)  \right) }+\ln 
 \left( x-1 \right) =0
$

Comment: You can also write your ODE as $$\frac{d(y/x)}{d(x+y)}=\frac{1+y/x}{y/x}$$ which is equivalent to daying $$d\Bigg(\frac{y}{x}-\ln\bigg|\frac{y}{x}+1\bigg|\Bigg)=d(x+y)$$

Comment: Had the $x^2$ been an $x^3$, the DE could be solved in seconds.